# CSS for completed mat-step in mat-vertical-stepper

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

In `mat-vertical-stepper` I have 4 `mat-step`. How can I have tick-mark once 1st step is completed?

I tried:

```
  <mat-vertical-stepper style="background:#f2ecec;" #stepper  [linear]="true">
    <mat-step label="General Details" [stepControl]="generalDetailsForm" completed="true" editable="true">
       <h3> Name </h3>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

If I make `editable="false"`, it is giving a tick mark and can't be editable as I made it `"false"`. 
Having only `completed="true"` I am not getting any tick mark at all.

need help for:

1. how to give tick once a mat-step is completed
2. after getting the tick mark, the tick mark should be in green(for which have to add CSS)

Answer (score 4):

## Update 05/18 (icons)

According to the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#overriding-icons), icons can now be customized like this:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
    <custom-icon>edit</custom-icon>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template matStepperIcon="done">
    <custom-icon>done</custom-icon>
  </ng-template>

  <!-- Stepper steps go here -->
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

## Original Post

In the official [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#linear-stepper), it says:

> Note that if both `completed` and `stepControl` are set, the `stepControl`
>   will take precedence.

So, if you want to use the completed attribute you need to delete your `stepControl`.

If you want to change the icon, you might have to wait for this [commit](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7384#issuecomment-353634143) to be merged. Also, have a look at the [MatStepHeader](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepHeader) directive. It has an `icon` input property you can set; e.g. `icon="done"` for your tick mark.

There does not seem to be an option to change the color via the API, yet. As a workaround, you could use something like:

```
/deep/ .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Please note that /deep/ and ::ng-deep are both currently deprecated. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the iconset instead of explicitly marking the step as completed.

```
 <mat-horizontal-stepper>
        <!-- Icon overrides. -->
        <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template matStepperIcon="done">
            <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template matStepperIcon="number">
            <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

For changing colors and other customizations please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/66428028/4184651