# How to create a progress wizard using angular material stepper

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a progress wizard using angular material stepper. I get JSON data that looks like this:

```
{
  "step":1,
  "info":"this is some order data",
  "status":true
},
 {
  "step":2,
   "info":"this is some order data",
  "status":true
},
 {
  "step":3,
  "info":"this is some order data",
  "status":false
}
```

If the status is true, then it should display green; if it's false, it should display grey color along with some info that I can display here. The stepper usually works with onlick only but I need it to work based on JSON status. Below is my code:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>

  <mat-step label="Step 1">
    Step 1 content
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step label="Step 2">
    Step 2 content
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step label="Step 3">
    You are now done.
  </mat-step>
  
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-angular-material-stepper-p4zkqw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mat-step pass the status value.
In your mat-step, add completed and state

<mat-step [completed]="status" [state]="state">
So that when status is true mat-step is completed and can also manipulate state in component.ts so that it is done when status is true

Refer : [How to show that the last mat-step is complete in mat-stepper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998794/how-to-show-that-the-last-mat-step-is-complete-in-mat-stepper)

Comment: for me it giving issue can u change it in my stackblitz ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-angular-material-stepper-p4zkqw giving me issues

Comment: Please check now. For now I have straight away added true false. But now that you see the behaviour, try to pass boolean value from JSON respectively.

Comment: where ? in stackblitz

Comment: Yes.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-angular-material-stepper-p4zkqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: nothing is there can u modify here in this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-angular-material-stepper-p4zkqw

Comment: Changed there only. Can you check if it is visible now.Else I can paste code here

Comment: app.component.html

<mat-horizontal-stepper>

  <mat-step label="Step 1">
    Step 1 content
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step [completed]="false" label="Step 2">
    Step 2 content
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step [completed]="true" label="Step 3">
    You are now done.
  </mat-step>
  
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

Comment: app.compoenent.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
 
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
   
  }
}